# How to auto login Facebook & Google If I have already logged in

Tags: android, authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

I have a condition. My app has two social logins Facebook & google but when users log out or delete app the social logins get disconnected. I want to both login user every time if the user has already logged in before even after they delete app and re-install.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm no Android expert but I believe that the way you are saving their login is through the APP's cache, which is saved on local storage (lmk if I'm wrong). So when a user deletes your App or re-installs it, the cache is removed along with it, therefore, as far as my knowledge goes I don't believe that what you are trying to accomplish is possible (I could be wrong though).

Unless you find a way to keep the cache on the phone even when your app is deleted by the user...

Best of luck my dude!